# Excel formula to check if cell contains quotation mark

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get excel to search cell to see if they contain `""` or `[]` in them but when I try to search for a quotation mark I get an error that the formula is wrong, if I search for text it works.

This is the formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"*",T3)),"OK", "Not OK")
```

Also after that how do I do a nested if statement to first check if it has `""` and then after to check if it has `[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below formula will identify if `""` or `[]` is present in a cell (just change `B8` to the cell your wanting to check):

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("""""",B8)>0)),"Ok",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("[]",B8)>0)),"Ok","Not Ok"))
```

The reason for using `ISERROR` in there is because if the value is not found, it will throw a `#VALUE` error and wont move onto the next nested if statement.

Comment: I tried this formula be when it gets to a cell with " it doesnt detect it and still says not ok. I only need to identify one " not ""

Comment: I fixed it, this answer works but can you please explain why you need to search for FIND("""""",B8) with 5 quotation marks if you want to find ""? and Why its """" for one "?

Comment: Sorry I thought by your question that you were looking for two double quotes. There's 6 in there in total. The reason for six is because the first one opens a string value, the second one is the string and the third one closes the string. By putting two lots of three in there, it searches for two double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CHAR()` function to search for the double quotes, it's based on the ASCII value, in this case 34:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&CHAR(34)&"*",T3)*SEARCH("*[]*",T3)),"OK","Not OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:
Assuming that the text is in cell B7 I have tried the following formula:

```
=IF((FIND("""""",B7)>0)* AND(FIND("[]",B7)>0),"Ok","Not Ok")
```